# Shifting all characters in a string to another character

Tags: r, string, vector

I have to write a function to move the characters of a string to another character, by a fixed number.
The vector of Letters is:

```
abc <- c(LETTERS+letters+" "+"."+","+"!"+"?")
```

When I have e.g. the text ".,!?" and the number I move the characters is 3, the "," should be a "?" but in stat of the "?" a "A" is the output.
my code:

```
text<- ".,!?"
move <- 3
abc <- c(LETTERS,letters, " ", ".",",","!","?")
  original <- strsplit(paste(text, collapse=""), "",fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
  crypt <- c()
  i <- 1
  for (i in 1:length(original)) {
    temp.pos <- which(abc==original[i])
    sub1 <- (temp.pos+move)/57 # The sub1 and 2 are for handle a number higher than the length of the vector abc
    sub2 <- floor(sub1)-1 
    crypt.pos <- sub1*57-sub2*57
    print(crypt.pos)
    l <- crypt.pos
    temp.letter <- abc[l]
    crypt <- c(crypt, temp.letter)
  }
```

I tried a few things but never get a "?" as output for the "."

Thank you.

Comment: `abc <- c(LETTERS+letters+" "+"."+","+"!"+"?")` is not R language. Have you defined the `+` operator for strings? You should include it.

Comment: to 1, I made a mistake by writing the here, if you look at my copied code with the for loop, there is the abc without the +. But Thank you ver much for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a for loop for what you are trying to achieve. You can also construct a named vector to do the character matching:

```
# the named vector
abc <- c(LETTERS,letters, " ", ".",",","!","?")
number <- 2
names(abc) = c(tail(abc,number),head(abc,length(abc)-number))

# test
str = c("ABCD,$")
paste(abc[strsplit(str,split="")[[1]]],collapse="")
```

Output:

```
[1] "CDEF?"
```

And if you want to keep characters than are not in your shift-vector:

```
str = c("ABCD,$")
splitted = strsplit(str,split="")[[1]]
new_str = abc[splitted]
new_str[is.na(new_str)] = splitted[is.na(new_str)]
paste(new_str,collapse="")
```

Output:

```
[1] "CDEF?$"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you ver much, the solution is genius, didn't thought about this solution.